# Will the stack be empty after this code executes?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm struggling with that bit of code. I'm not sure if the stack will be empty upon the code execution. Is there anything that I'm missing?

```py
s1 = Stack()
q = Queue()
s1.push(1)
s1.push(2)
s1.push(3)
while not s1.isEmpty():
    q.enqueue(s1.pop())
print(q.dequeue(), end = ' ')
print(q.dequeue(), end = ' ')
print(q.dequeue(), end = ' ')
```

Comment: Welcome, but please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please paste your code as text into the question

Comment: Posted the code as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the stack will be empty after this code executes.

This is very easy to demonstrate: the `while` loop's condition is `not s1.isEmpty()`, so if the stack is not empty then the loop keeps going. Therefore, if the print statements after the loop are reached, it must be because the condition `not s1.isEmpty()` became false, and hence the stack is empty. Nothing else is then pushed to the stack in between that point and the end of the program, so the stack remains empty.

More generally, whenever you have a `while` loop with some condition, and that loop has no `break` statement allowing it to terminate for some other reason, then we can assert that the condition is definitely false whenever the line immediately after the loop is reached:

```py
while condition:
    # no break statements in the loop
    # ...

# whenever this line of code is reached, the condition must be false
assert not condition
```

This is a simple but very powerful way of reasoning about the behaviour of programs with loops.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Wasnt sure i had it right :D Thanks